# cocos2d-x : setCatgoryBitmask not working

Tags: cocos2d-x, collision

For some reason the function `setBatgoryBitmask()` of a `PhysicsBody` in cocos2d-x has no effect :

```
    OutputDebugStringA("Wall cat bitmask : ");
    OutputDebugStringA(std::to_string(body->getCategoryBitmask()).c_str());
    OutputDebugStringA("\n");
    body->setCategoryBitmask(2);
    OutputDebugStringA("Wall cat bitmask : ");
    OutputDebugStringA(std::to_string(body->getCategoryBitmask()).c_str());
    OutputDebugStringA("\n");
    body->addShape(PhysicsShapeEdgeBox::create(Size(dest - or ), mat, borderW));
    OutputDebugStringA("Wall cat bitmask : ");
    OutputDebugStringA(std::to_string(body->getCategoryBitmask()).c_str());
    OutputDebugStringA("\n");
```

Result :

```
Wall cat bitmask : -1
Wall cat bitmask : -1
Wall cat bitmask : -1
```

As a result I cannot define what collide with what. Both `setCategoryBitmask` and `getCategoryBitmask` seems to be simplet setter and getter however so I have no idea what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that is stupid. Seems that you cannot set category or collision bitmask if your body has no shape yet. Setting those after adding the first shape seems to resolve the problem.